Flow Error: Input Variable "recordId" Doesn't Exist in Active Flow Version
I am encountering an issue with a Lightning Web Component (LWC) that invokes a screen flow. Despite having the recordId set up as an Input Variable in the flow and marked as Available for Input, I keep getting the following error:
"The input variable recordId doesn't exist in the active version of the flow Show_Sales_orders."
Here is what I have tried so far:
Confirmed that the recordId input variable exists in the active version of the flow and is marked as available for input.
Verified the LWC is correctly passing the input variables as shown below:
updateFlowInputVariables() {
    this.inputVariables = [
        {
            name: 'recordId',
            type: 'String',
            value: this.recordId
        }
    ];
    this.flowKey = `${this.recordId}-${Date.now()}`; // Force re-render
}

Debugged the following:
The recordId is being logged correctly in the console.
inputVariables is being populated as expected.
The flowKey is being generated dynamically to re-render the flow.
Ensured that the flow is active and accessible, with no validation rule or permission issues.
Despite these steps, the flow either fails with the above error or remains idle (doesn't execute).
Debug Logs:
Received recordId in LWC: axxxxxxxxxxxxx
Input Variables: [{"name":"recordId","type":"String","value":"axxxxxxxxxxxxx"}]
Flow Key: axxxxxxxxxxxxx-1732304247089
Flow Status: Error
<template if:true={flowKey}>
    <lightning-flow
        key={flowKey}
        flow-api-name="Show_Sales_orders"
        flow-input-variables={inputVariables}
        onstatuschange={handleStatusChange}>
    </lightning-flow>
</template>

Has anyone faced a similar issue? What could I be missing or overlooking here? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

recordId is case sensitive variable name - are you sure in the Flow it is defined as a variable recordId and not recordid ?

yes it is recordId and not recordid.
